# PythonChess - Get engine to predict a list of the best moves in a position

Tags: engines, software, programming, python

Say that I currently have a board, and then on that board I move my e2 pawn to e4. I'm looking for a way to get the engine to predict the X amount of best moves for black.

I know how to predict the best move given a position:

```
result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1))
board.push(result.move)
```

But that only predicts the number 1 best move. I want a list containing the second, third ... X best moves.

How would I do that?

Comment: What you are asking for is known as multiPV. In the documentation for engine.analyse(), read about the multipv optional parameter. I would have posted this as an answer -- to the closers, note that asking an engine for the X best moves is **very different** from all moves, they are not even accomplished with the same technique, so please don't close so hastily questions that only *seem* similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the world of chess engines, what you're looking for is called **multi-PV** (multiple principal variations): telling the engine to look for and return up to *n* best moves and the associated principal variations for each. ("Up to" because sometimes there's only 1 legal move in a position.)

In python-chess, this is part of the [engine protocols](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html), as one of the optional parameters when calling `engine.analyse()`. From the documentation:

> `class chess.engine.EngineProtocol`
>
> `coroutine analyse( [...] )`
>
> - multipv – Optional. Analyse multiple root moves. Will return a list of at most multipv dictionaries rather than just a single info dictionary.

The `.analyse()` method tells the engine to analyse the position, returning a [dictionary of information](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html#chess.engine.PlayResult.info), which includes among other things the moves of the principal variation. Specifying for instance `.analyse(multipv = 3)` will tell the engine to return a list of (up to) 3 such dictionaries -- the first moves in the `pv` value of each dictionary should be what you are looking for.